# How to concatenate a large number of text files in python

Tags: python, concatenation

I have 367 text files I want to concatenate into one long text file. I was thinking I could go about this by doing:

```
filenames = ["file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"...]
with open("output_file.txt","w") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            contents = infile.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
```

However, this would require me to write out every single text file name, which would be very tedious. Is there an easier way to concatenate a large number of text files using Python? Thank you!

Comment: You either type them, or you generate them.  Also your `write()` is probably not what you want.  Maybe the `read()` too.  Tried it with test files?

Comment: Is there some pattern to all the filenames? You can use `glob.glob()` to find all the filenames matching a pattern.

Comment: If they're in a folder, then you could iterate over that folder. Or if there's any logic about which files you want to select. But if they're just randomly scrambled and selected around the computer, then yes, you have to write them out manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to build list files and [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) for a more efficient copy.

```
import shutil
import glob

filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")  # or "file*.txt"
with open("output_file.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these files all have a counter (1-367) in the format `filename-count-.extension`, we can generate 367 files using list comprehension.

```
filenames = [f'file{i}.txt' for i in range(1,368)]
with open("output_file.txt","w") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            contents = infile.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
```

another option you could use is `os.listdir`.

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('files'):
    print(i)
```

output

```
text1.txt
text2.txt
```